# Continuous recording in PortAudio (from mic or output)

Tags: c, audio, portaudio

I am trying to create a music visualizer application in PortAudio, I did some basic research and found some examples on how to record from a mic to a (temporary) file. But there was no example where the data is not used runtime during the recording.

So how can I start a continuous audio-stream where I can catch the data from the current "frame"?

This is how I tried to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "portaudio.h"

#define SAMPLE_RATE (44100)

typedef struct{
    int frameIndex;
    int maxFrameIndex;
    char* recordedSamples;
}
testData;

PaStream* stream;

static int recordCallback(const void* inputBuffer, void* outputBuffer, unsigned long frameCount, const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo, PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void* userData){
    testData* data = (testData*)userData;
    const char* buffer_ptr = (const char*)inputBuffer;
    char* index_ptr = &data->recordedSamples[data->frameIndex];

    long framesToCalc;
    long i;
    int finished;
    unsigned long framesLeft = data->maxFrameIndex - data->frameIndex;

    if(framesLeft < frameCount){
        framesToCalc = framesLeft;
        finished = paComplete;
    }else{
        framesToCalc = frameCount;
        finished = paContinue;
    }

    if(inputBuffer == NULL){
        for(i = 0; i < framesToCalc; i++){
            *index_ptr++ = 0;
        }
    }else{
        for(i = 0; i < framesToCalc; i++){
            *index_ptr++ = *buffer_ptr++;
        }
    }

    data->frameIndex += framesToCalc;
    return finished;
}

int setup(testData streamData){
    PaError err;

    err = Pa_Initialize();
    if(err != paNoError){
        fprintf(stderr, "Pa_Initialize error: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
        return 1;
    }

    PaStreamParameters inputParameters;
    inputParameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice();
    if (inputParameters.device == paNoDevice) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: No default input device.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    inputParameters.channelCount = 1;
    inputParameters.sampleFormat = paInt8;
    inputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(inputParameters.device)->defaultLowInputLatency;
    inputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

    err = Pa_OpenStream(&stream, &inputParameters, NULL, SAMPLE_RATE, 256, paClipOff, recordCallback, &streamData);
    if(err != paNoError){
        fprintf(stderr, "Pa_OpenDefaultStream error: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
        return 1;
    }

    err = Pa_StartStream(stream);
    if(err != paNoError){
        fprintf(stderr, "Pa_StartStream error: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void quit(testData streamData){
    PaError err;
    err = Pa_Terminate();
    if(err != paNoError){
        fprintf(stderr, "Pa_Terminate error: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
    }

    if(streamData.recordedSamples)
        free(streamData.recordedSamples);
}

int main(){
    int i;
    PaError err;
    testData streamData = {0};

    streamData.frameIndex = 0;
    streamData.maxFrameIndex = SAMPLE_RATE;
    streamData.recordedSamples = (char*)malloc(SAMPLE_RATE * sizeof(char));
    if(streamData.recordedSamples == NULL)
        printf("Could not allocate record array.\n");

    for(i=0; i<SAMPLE_RATE; i++) 
        streamData.recordedSamples[i] = 0;

    //int totalFrames = SAMPLE_RATE;

    if(!setup(streamData)){
        printf("Opened\n");

        int i = 0;

        while(i++ < 500){

            if((err = Pa_GetStreamReadAvailable(stream)) != paNoError)
                break;

            while((err = Pa_IsStreamActive(stream)) == 1){
                Pa_Sleep(1000);
            }

            err = Pa_CloseStream(stream);
            if(err != paNoError)
                break;

            streamData.frameIndex = 0;
            for(i=0; i<SAMPLE_RATE; i++) 
                streamData.recordedSamples[i] = 0;
        }

        if(err != paNoError){
            fprintf(stderr, "Active stream error: %s\n", Pa_GetErrorText(err));
        }

        quit(streamData);
    }else{
        puts("Couldn't open\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it gives the following output:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
Active stream error: Can't read from a callback stream
```

Comment: What platform are you working on?

Comment: I am working on Debian Linux (64 bit)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Update*:

What is the purpose of this code?

```
        if((err = Pa_GetStreamReadAvailable(stream)) != paNoError)
            break;
```

It seems to me like this is causing your (latest) problem. Why do you need to retrieve (and then discard) the number of frames that can be read from the stream without waiting, which would presumably be zero since stream is a callback stream?

---

*Previous answer:*

This seems highly suspicious:

```
static void* data;
/* ... */
static int recordCallback(const void* inputBuffer, void* outputBuffer, unsigned long frameCount, const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo, PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void* userData){
    testData* data = (testData*)userData;
    /* ... */
}
```

Firstly, why are there two variables named `data`? That's just silly... Can you think of more appropriate identifiers?

Secondly, you're passing a `&data` (a `void **`) to Pa_OpenStream. Presumably, Pa_OpenStream passes that same value on to your callback function, where you treat that pointer to `void *` as though it points to a `testData *`. That's undefined behaviour.

Remove <strike>`static void* data;`</strike>. That's not necessary, here. Declare a new `testData data = { 0 };` inside main, right at the very top. Now you're passing a `testData *` (converted to `void *`) to Pa_OpenStream, Pa_OpenStream will pass that on to your callback where you can safely convert it back to a `testData *` as you are. You might want to set the members of `data` before calling Pa_OpenStream...

Comment: Thank you for pointing those errors out, I have tried to fix them the best I could but the error still remains; I don't think it has anything to do with memory allocation because now (see updated question) I still get the `Active stream error: Can't read from a callback stream` error. So it breaks on the `Pa_GetStreamReadAvailable` call, but I do have a usable microphone connected to my computer. I would also like the alternative of using the sound my own computer sends as an output.

Comment: I didn't have time to check your answer but since the time for the points is almost ended I'll grant it to you; I'll check it later this day!

Comment: Well, let me know how this works out... I very much dislike ALSA, but I'm always happy to learn. I'll help you figure out what's wrong...

Comment: Ah I finally got a half hour to look at it, it does go to the loop when I remove that statement; but I have no idea how to get the data, when I add `fprintf(stderr, "Stream: %s\n", data->recordedSamples);` to the recordCallback function I get `Stream: H�$�#` once, and when I add it to the while loop it remains empty!

Comment: @ThomasVersteeg Is there any evidence to suggest that `data->recordedSamples` points to a string (ie. that it's guaranteed to be `'\0'` terminated)? If not, then `%s` might not be the correct format specifier. Perhaps, since that data might contain non-printable bytes, you might wish to dump it as hex: `fprintf(stderr, "Stream: "); for (x = 0; x < data->frameIndex; x++) { fprintf("%X", (unsigned char) data->recordedSamples[x]); } putchar('\n');`

Comment: I tried adding your piece of code on various places in my source code but all I get is an empty `Stream: `; and when I add it in the while loop above `Pa_Sleep()` I get a whole stream of `Stream: ` and it quits with code 139 (segfault).

Answer (score 2):

To interact with the data stream real-time you'll need a mechanism that either sleeps (busy waits on Windows) for the frame period (sample rate / samples per frame) or uses a thread synchronization primitive to trigger your thread `int main` that there is audio ready to be processed.  This will give you access to each frame of data that PortAudio delivers during its callback (called from the PortAudio thread).  Here's how the concept works using `boost::condition` and `boost::mutex`.

```
//CAUTION THIS SNIPPET IS ONLY INTENDED TO DEMONSTRATE HOW ONE MIGHT
//SYNCHRONIZE WITH THE PORTAUDIO THREAD

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/condition.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/scoped_lock.hpp>

#include "portaudio.h"

boost::condition waitForAudio;
boost::mutex waitForAudioMutex;
boost::mutex audioBufferMutex;
bool trigger = false;

std::deque<char> audioBuffer;

static int recordCallback(const void* inputBuffer, void* outputBuffer, unsigned long frameCount, const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo, PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags, void* userData){

    const char* buffer_ptr = (const char*)inputBuffer;

    //Lock mutex to block user thread from modifying data buffer
    audioBufferMutex.lock();

    //Copy data to user buffer
    for(i = 0; i < frameCount; ++i) {
       audioBuffer.push_back(buffer_ptr + i);
    }

    //Unlock mutex, allow user to manipulate buffer
    audioBufferMutex.unlock();

    //Signal user thread to process audio
    waitForAudioMutex.lock();
    trigger= true;
    waitForAudio.notify_one();
    waitForAudioMutex.unlock();

    return finished;
}

int main(){
        Pa_Initialize();
        //OPEN AND START PORTAUDIO STREAM
        while(true){ //Catch signal (Ctrl+C) or some other mechanism to interrupt this loop
            boost::xtime duration;
            boost::xtime_get(&duration, boost::TIME_UTC);
            boost::interprocess::scoped_lock<boost::mutex> lock(waitForAudioMutex);
            if(!trigger) {
                if(!waitForAudio.timed_wait(lock, duration)) {
                    //Condition timed out -- assume audio stream failed
                    break;
                }
            }
            trigger= false;

            audioBufferMutex.lock();
            //VISUALIZE AUDIO HERE
            //JUST MAKE SURE TO FINISH BEFORE PORTAUDIO MAKES ANOTHER CALLBACK
            audioBufferMutex.unlock();
        }
        //STOP AND CLOSE PORTAUDIO STEAM
        Pa_Terminate();
        return 0;
    }
```

Generally, this technique is cross-platform, however this specific implementation may only work on Linux.  On Windows use `SetEvent(eventVar)` in place of `condition::notify_one()` and `WaitForSingleObject(eventVar, duration)` instead of `condition::timed_wait(lock, duration)`.

Comment: @AshishK what is your doubt?

Comment: Hi @trukvl request your suggestion on this please (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44645466/portaudio-real-time-audio-processing-for-continuous-input-stream)

Answer (score 0):

You closed the stream `err = Pa_CloseStream(stream);` in the first iteration. In the second iteration, the channel was already closed. Try the operation `err = Pa_CloseStream(stream);` after all iterations.

Comment: When I remove the line you pointed out I still don't get the data.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it this way:

```
    PaStreamParameters  inputParameters ,outputParameters;
    PaStream*           stream;
    PaError             err;  
    paTestData          data;
    int                 i;
    int                 totalFrames;
    int                 numSamples;
    int                 numBytes;

    err                     = paNoError;
    inputParameters.device  = 4;

    data.maxFrameIndex      = totalFrames = NUM_SECONDS * SAMPLE_RATE;
    data.frameIndex         = 0;
    numSamples              = totalFrames * NUM_CHANNELS;
    numBytes                = numSamples * sizeof(SAMPLE);
    data.recordedSamples    = (SAMPLE *) malloc( numBytes );

    std::ofstream arch;
    arch.open("signal.csv");

    err = Pa_Initialize();
    inputParameters.channelCount = 1;                    
    inputParameters.sampleFormat = PA_SAMPLE_TYPE;
    inputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo( inputParameters.device )->defaultLowInputLatency;
    inputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

    int contador = 0;
    bool strec = true;
    while (strec)
    {
        err = Pa_OpenStream(
              &stream,
              &inputParameters,
              NULL,                  
              SAMPLE_RATE,
              FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
              paClipOff,      
              recordCallback,
              &data );

        err = Pa_StartStream( stream );

        printf("\n===Grabando.... ===\n"); fflush(stdout);
        Pa_Sleep(3000);
        while( ( err = Pa_IsStreamActive(stream) ) == 1 )
        {

        }

        err = Pa_CloseStream( stream );

        for( i=0; i<numSamples; i++ )

        {

            val = data.recordedSamples[i];

            arch << val << std::endl;
            std::cout << std::endl << "valor  : " << val;
        }

        data.frameIndex = 0;
        contador++;
        if (contador >= 100) //if you delete this condition continuously recorded this audio
        {
            strec = false;
            arch.close();
        }
    }
```