# How do I do real time audio capture and processing with port audio in a for loop in C?

Tags: windows, audio, audio-streaming, audio-recording, portaudio

I have added the code below. I am able to capture audio using the mic, I can capture it all at the same time. My ultimate goal is to do real time audio processing. so in the for loop, I will capture audio process it and put the output in a file.
Using the code below, I can only capture the audio in the first pass of the for loop, the same audio gets copied into the `Cinput` variable in the rest of the loops. Is there a way to capture real time audio and do the processing with minimum latency using port audio? This is the only cross platform API I found which I could use. Currently I am working with Visual studio on Windows 8 in C. But, later on I could be dealing with Linux or Mac.

```
    PaStreamParameters inputparameters;
    PaStream* stream;
    PaError err = paNoError;
    paTestData data;
    data.maxFrameIndex = chunkSz * 100;
    data.frameIndex = 0;
        err = Pa_Initialize();
        if (err != paNoError) return;
        inputparameters.device = Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice();
        if (inputparameters.device == paNoDevice) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: No default input device.\n");
            return;
        }

        inputparameters.channelCount = 2;
        inputparameters.sampleFormat = paInt16;
        inputparameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(inputparameters.device)->defaultLowInputLatency;
        inputparameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;

    data.livebuf = (short*)malloc(sizeof(short)*(chunkSz)* 100 * 2);

    short *Cinput;
    Cinput = (short*)malloc(10*chunkSz * 2 *100* sizeof(short));
    memset(Cinput, 0, sizeof(short)*10*100*2*chunkSz);
    int newwtemp = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

        err = Pa_OpenStream(&stream, &inputparameters, NULL, 8000, chunkSz * 100, paClipOff, recordCallback, &data);
        if (err != paNoError) {
            printf("Exiting from Openstream\n");
            return;
        }
    err = Pa_StartStream(stream);
    if (err != paNoError) { 
        printf("Exit from start stream\n");
        return; }
    //printf("\n\n...................now Recording! please speak into the mike....................\n\n"); fflush(stdout);

    while ((err = Pa_IsStreamActive(stream)) == 1)
    {
        Pa_Sleep(1);
        //printf("index = %d\n", data.frameIndex); fflush(stdout);
    }
    if (err < 0) {
        printf("In Is stream active error return\n");
        return;
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < chunkSz*100 * 2; k++){
        Cinput[newwtemp] = data.livebuf[k];
    //  data.livebuf[k] = 0;
        newwtemp++;
    }
    Pa_StopStream(stream);
}
    err = Pa_CloseStream(stream);
    if (err != paNoError){ return; }
       FILE  *fid;
       fid = fopen("recorded.raw", "wb");
       if (fid == NULL)
       {
           printf("Could not open file.");
       }
       else
       {
           fwrite(Cinput, sizeof(short), chunkSz *10* 100*2, fid);
           fclose(fid);
           printf("Wrote data to 'recorded.raw'\n");
       }
       //////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: Why not just write it out in the callback?

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690668/continuous-recording-in-portaudio-from-mic-or-output/16754117#16754117